# Best hyperparameters from GridSearch give inverted results compared to the actual SMOreg prediction results

Tags: svm, weka, grid-search, hyperparameters

I am a beginner in Machine Learning, and I have a question regarding the results of Grid Search to find the best hyperparameters of C and gamma for SMOreg.

I am doing Grid Search to find the best C and gamma that will give me the highest correlation. I am using GridSearch as shown below:

**weka.classifiers.meta.GridSearch -E CC -y-property kernel.gamma -y-min -3.0 -y-max 3.0 -y-step 1.0 -y-base 10.0 -y-expression pow(BASE,I) -x-property C -x-min -3.0 -x-max 3.0 -x-step 1.0 -x-base 10.0 -x-expression pow(BASE,I) -sample-size 100.0 -traversal ROW-WISE -log-file "D:\Program Files\Weka-3-9-4" -num-slots 1 -S 1 -W weka.classifiers.functions.SMOreg -- -C 1.0 -N 0 -I "weka.classifiers.functions.supportVector.RegSMOImproved -T 0.001 -V -P 1.0E-12 -L 0.001 -W 1" -K "weka.classifiers.functions.supportVector.RBFKernel -C 250007 -G 0.01"**

As shown above, I set the evaluation into CC (Correlation Coefficient), the XProperty into C and YProperty into kernel.gamma, with both the C and the gamma parameters ranging from 10^-3,10^-2,10^-1,1,10,100, and 1000. It should be noted that I use SMOreg as the base classifier and RBFKernel as the kernel function. Furthermore, I set the evaluation metrics into Correlation, MAE, RMSE, and MAPE.

The hyperparameter output of the GridSearch is shown below:

**weka.classifiers.meta.GridSearch:
Classifier: weka.classifiers.functions.SMOreg -C 1.0 -N 0 -I "weka.classifiers.functions.supportVector.RegSMOImproved -T 0.001 -V -P 1.0E-12 -L 0.001 -W 1" -K "weka.classifiers.functions.supportVector.RBFKernel -C 250007 -G 10.0"**

**X property: C**

**Y property: kernel.gamma**

**Evaluation: Correlation coefficient**

**Coordinates: [0.0, 1.0]**

**Values: 1.0 (X coordinate), 10.0 (Y coordinate)**

The meaning of this result is that the best value for C is 1 and the best gamma is 10

At the end of the GridSearch result, the following summary data is shown:

**=== Summary ===**

**Correlation coefficient                  0.945**

**Mean absolute percentage error           0.1434**

**Mean absolute error                      3.8465**

**Root mean squared error                  5.5417**

**Total Number of Instances              309**

This implies that, by using the C=1 and gamma=10 respectively, the prediction result should be the one showed in the summary above.

However, when I am doing an SMOreg with the same dataset using the best parameters acquired from the GridSearch (C=1 and gamma=10), I get different results as shown below:

The classifier:

**weka.classifiers.functions.SMOreg -C 1.0 -N 0 -I "weka.classifiers.functions.supportVector.RegSMOImproved -T 0.001 -V -P 1.0E-12 -L 0.001 -W 1" -K "weka.classifiers.functions.supportVector.RBFKernel -C 250007 -G 10.0"**

The output:

**=== Summary ===**

**Correlation coefficient                  0.9417**

**Mean absolute percentage error           0.1381**

**Mean absolute error                      3.7672**

**Root mean squared error                  5.7114**

**Total Number of Instances              309**

Funny thing is, if I invert the best hyperparameters result (C=10, gamma=1), I get the perfectly similar result to the GridSearch prediction result:

The classifier:

**weka.classifiers.functions.SMOreg -C 10.0 -N 0 -I "weka.classifiers.functions.supportVector.RegSMOImproved -T 0.001 -V -P 1.0E-12 -L 0.001 -W 1" -K "weka.classifiers.functions.supportVector.RBFKernel -C 250007 -G 1.0"**

The output:

**=== Summary ===**

**Correlation coefficient                  0.945**

**Mean absolute percentage error           0.1434**

**Mean absolute error                      3.8465**

**Root mean squared error                  5.5417**

**Total Number of Instances              309**

Does anyone know why this happens?

One more thing: In the GridSearch, the maximum search space for both C and gamma is 1000. However, I tried using C=100, and gamma=1 and it gave better/higher Correlation Coefficient number compared to the best hyperparameters according to the GridSearch which is C=1 and gamma=10. Why the GridSearch didn't give the best results?

Thank you.